# [REQ_RESOURCE_TYPE]: The resource must be a string, Buffer or a valid file stream

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, discord, discord.js

I Am Trying To Do Some GreyScale Effect In Pictures But When I Do The Command, It's Show me the error Above...

Any Fix?

***The Code :***

```js
const jimp = require('jimp')
const {MessageAttachment} = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name:'grey',
    run:async(client, message, args)=>{
        if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
            let image = message.attachments.first().url; 
            if(!image) return;
            let readedImage = await jimp.read(image);
            let sendedImage = await readedImage.greyscale()
            let attch = new MessageAttachment(sendedImage,'Skyy.png');
            message.channel.send(attch);
          }
        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must convert the jimp image to a buffer before sending it:

```js
const jimp = require('jimp')
const {MessageAttachment} = require('discord.js')
module.exports = {
    name:'grey',
    run:async(client, message, args)=>{
        if (message.attachments.size > 0) {
            let image = message.attachments.first().url; 
            if(!image) return;
            let readedImage = await jimp.read(image);
            // changed line below
            let sendedImage = await readedImage.greyscale().getBufferAsync();
            let attch = new MessageAttachment(sendedImage,'Skyy.png');
            message.channel.send(attch);
          }
        

    }
}
```